# Recovering electric charge from potential

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics

I have a region $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and a harmonic function $\phi$ on $\Omega$. I know that for some "charge" $Q:\partial \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$,

$$\phi(q) = \int_{\partial \Omega} Q(p)G(p,q)\,dp,$$

where $G(p,q)$ is the Green's function of $\Delta$. Is there a way to "deconvolve" $\phi$ to recover $Q$?

Comment: If you were working in 3d, how (quantitatively) would the presence of a boundary charge layer affect the electric field?

Comment: What about Laplace equation $\Delta\phi=Q$?

Comment: You need to look carefully at the boundary integral for $q$ inside, outside, and on the boundary.  Answer whether $\phi$ is continous at the boundary.  Answer whether any component of $\nabla \phi$ is continous at the boundary.

Comment: Of course, I meant Poisson eq. Plus there is a sign missing in what wrote.

Comment: @MASL I'm not sure how that helps... $\Delta\phi=0$ inside $\Omega$, the $Q$ I'm trying to find is on the boundary.

Comment: @Dr.MV Let's say $\phi$ and $\nabla \phi \cdot \hat{n}$ are both continuous... does this allow a standard technique for finding $Q$?

Comment: @user7530: $\nabla \phi \cdot \hat{n}$ being continuous would imply that the surface charge density $Q$ that you're looking for is zero; in fact $Q$ is proportional to the jump in the perpendicular field strength at $\partial\Omega$. The problem is that you only have $\phi$ in the interior, so you can't evaluate the perpendicular field strength on the outside to find the jump.

Comment: Or, if you just meant that $\nabla \phi \cdot \hat{n}$ is continuous on $\Omega$: This is true simply because there's no charge in the interior; it's not an additional assumption that would help you to find $Q$.

Comment: @joriki You are right, I suppose what I mean is that $\nabla \phi$ is continuous up to $\partial \Omega$.

Comment: @MASL How do you take the Laplacian at a point on the boundary? I only know $\phi$ on $\Omega$, not on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Some days I should just shut up for the whole day. Your Q is the charge not the charge density, even less, the volumetric charge density as appears in the Poisson equation. Indeed, at a surface charge distribution, Q is determined by the electrical field discontinuity relations as Dr.MV argues below. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Heuristic Development**

We examine the behavior or $\nabla \phi$ across the boundary $\Omega$.  In particular, we will heuristically evaluate the limit

$$\lim_{\nu \to 0^+}\left(\nabla \phi(\vec \rho+\hat n\nu)-\nabla \phi(\vec \rho-\hat n\nu)\right)$$

where $\hat n$ is the unit normal to the boundary $\partial \Omega$ at the point $\vec \rho$. First we write

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \phi(\vec \rho+\hat n\nu)-\nabla \phi(\vec \rho-\hat n\nu)&=\int_{\partial \Omega} Q(\vec \rho')\left(\nabla G(\vec \rho+\hat n\nu|\vec \rho')-\nabla G(\vec \rho-\hat n\nu|\vec \rho')\right)d\ell'\\\\
&=\int_{\partial \Omega-C_{\delta}} Q(\vec \rho')\left(\nabla G(\vec \rho+\hat n\nu|\vec \rho')-\nabla G(\vec \rho-\hat n\nu|\vec \rho')\right)d\ell'\\\\
&+\int_{C_{\delta}} Q(\vec \rho')\left(\nabla G(\vec \rho+\hat n\nu|\vec \rho')-\nabla G(\vec \rho-\hat n\nu|\vec \rho')\right)d\ell' \tag 1
\end{align}$$

where $C_{\delta}$ is a section of $\partial \Omega$ with arc length $2\delta$ and that contains $\vec \rho$ at the "midpoint."  In that which follows, the development relies on heuristic arguments, which can be made rigorous, to facilitate.

With fixed $\delta$, the first integral in the right-hand side of $(1)$ goes to zero as $\nu\to 0$ by continuity of $G(\vec \rho|\vec \rho')$ for $\vec \rho\ne \vec \rho'$.

Now, we take $\delta$ small enough so that locally we can "approximate" $C_{\delta}$ by a straight line path of length $2\delta$ (i.e., locally $C_{\delta}$ has zero curvature).  Furthermore, we exploit the continuity of $Q(\vec \rho')$ on $C_{\delta}$ and write $Q(\vec \rho')\approx Q(\vec \rho)$.  Then the second integral of $(1)$ can be approximated by

$$\begin{align}
\int_{C_{\delta}} Q(\vec \rho')\left(\nabla G(\vec \rho+\hat n\nu|\vec \rho')-\nabla G(\vec \rho-\hat n\nu|\vec \rho')\right)d\ell'&\approx Q(\vec \rho)\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{2\nu}{\rho'^2+\nu^2}\right)\,d\rho'\\\\
&=Q(\vec \rho)\frac{1}{2\pi}\left. \left(2\arctan\left(\frac{\delta}{\nu}\right)\right)\right|_{-\delta}^{\delta}\\\\
&=Q(\vec \rho)\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{\delta}{\nu}\right)\\\\
&\to Q(\vec \rho)\,\,\text{as}\,\,\nu\to 0^+
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{\nu \to 0^+}\left(\nabla \phi(\vec \rho+\hat n\nu)-\nabla \phi(\vec \rho-\hat n\nu)\right)=Q(\vec \rho)}$$

Comment: Thanks... so overall the approach would be to solve the Laplace equation on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \Omega$ using $\phi_{\partial \Omega}$ as Dirichlet boundary conditions, and then to look at the gradient jump.

Comment: Yes, this is the Dirichlet solution with $Q$ the normal derivative of $\phi$.  However, please note that in this development, $\partial \Omega$ was not required to be a closed contour (hence the difference of the normal derivative was applied).  So, the interpretation is a bit broader than the exterior solution of Laplace's equation.  Interesting question and a big +1 for the post!